# Concatenate with Spaces

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I am using concatenate to merge a month and a serial #.

The end result though is something like Oct809900036.
I need the final view to be Oct 809900036 though, what is the best way to do this whilst maintaining the formulas down the sheet.
Have tried Text To Columns but not luck as i need the final product to still sit in the same cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use " " as an additional parameter, i.e.:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1," ",B1)
```

or shorter:

```
=A1&" "&B1
```

(where `A1` is your month and `B1` your ID)

Comment: thought it would be something like that, thank you very much